# Find the maximum value of $3\sin{\theta \over 2} (1+\cos{\theta} )$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Find the maximum value of $3(\sin{\theta \over 2}) (1+\cos{\theta} )$.

I tried A.M-GM. but the equality doesn't hold for any value . Please help me!

Comment: Add some brackets to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Double angle formula.

Comment: Ohhhh!ho! I am done! Thanks all of you for helping!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as OP got his answer after posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building upon OP's idea of AM-GM, let $\,t = \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2}\,$, then $\,3\sin{\dfrac{\theta}{2}} (1+\cos{\theta} ) = 6t(1-t^2)\,$, and the square of the expression is:

$$\require{cancel}
36 t^2(1-t^2)^2 = 18 \cdot (2t^2)(1-t^2)(1-t^2) \le 18 \cdot \left(\frac{\cancel{(2t^2)}+(1-\cancel{t^2})+(1-\cancel{t^2})}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{16}{3}
$$

Therefore the maximum is $\,\sqrt{\dfrac{16}{3}}=\dfrac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\,$, attained at $\,2t^2=1-t^2\,$ i.e. $\,t = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\sin \dfrac{\theta}{2}\,$.

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: Welcome to the club of mysterious downvoters ! $\to +1$. I felt that I could use a similar approach without AM-GM. If you mind, I shall delete my answer. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Nothing for me to mind at all, quite the contrary. Your answer well covers the other possible interpretation of OP's comment `done`.

Answer (score 3):

*This is very similar to dxiv's solution but does not use $AM-GM$.*

Using the double angle formula
$$f=3 \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) (1+\cos (\theta ))=3 \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)\left(1+1-2\sin^2 \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)\right)=6 \sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right) \left(1-\sin ^2\left(\frac{\theta
   }{2}\right)\right)$$
Let $t=\sin \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)$ to make 
$$f=6t(1-t^2)=6t-6t^3$$
$$f'=6-18t^2$$
$$f''=-36t$$
So, the first derivative cancels for $t=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ and since you look for the maximum, you need $f'' <0$ then $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ is the solution.

So, the maximum value is $\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}$ and it will be reached at $\theta=2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$ (the value of which is not asked).

Comment: `This is very similar to ...` Not at all, and as far as the starting point both our answers are tributary to @xbh's [terse comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2883123/find-the-maximum-value-of-3-sin-theta-over-2-1-cos-theta/2883142#comment5953047_2883123) `Double angle formula` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The following Mathematica code

```
Maximize[3*Sin[x/2]*(1 + Cos[x]), x]
```

gives

the maximum

$$(x^*,y^*) = \left(4 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}}\right),3 \sin \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}}\right)\right) \left(1+\cos
   \left(4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

or

$$(x^*,y^*) \approx (1.23096,2.3094)$$

Comment: You could have asked for a simplification to get $$\left\{\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}},\left\{x\to 4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{5-2
   \sqrt{6}}\right)\right\}\right\}$$